# How to make an ArrayList with two Firestore collection?

Tags: android, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to load RecyclerView from my firestone db. My firestore structure is like this:

users(collection) -> user_id(document) -> books(collection)
books(collection) -> book_id(document)

Added: Database structure images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVjVt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYonZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcmQL.png)

What I want to do is getting the book_ids of current_user into an `ArrayList<String>`  then with this arraylist and for each loop, I want to load books into another `ArrayList<Book>`. I am getting the “ArrayList  book_ids” of the current user. (I want to show the books which were added by current user)
The problem is with this array list I can not manage to get `ArrayList<Book>books`. I will send this array list to recycler view adapter.

```
        public void getBookIdsFromDb(){
    final ArrayList<String> myBookIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    CollectionReference bookIdRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.collection_users)).document(userId)
            .collection(getString(R.string.colleciton_books));

    bookIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()){
                    myBookIds.add(ds.getString("book_id"));
                   myBookIds.size());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: myBookIds.size" + myBookIds.size());
                if (myBookIds.size()>0){
                    getMyBooksFromDb(myBookIds);
                    //this works
                }


            }
        }
    });
}
public void getMyBooksFromDb(ArrayList<String> bookIds){
    final ArrayList<String> myBooksIds =bookIds;
    final ArrayList<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    CollectionReference dbRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.colleciton_books));
    for (int i =0; i<myBooksIds.size();i++){
        Log.d(TAG, "getMyBooksFromDb: myBookIds in for " + myBooksIds.size());

dbRef.document(myBooksIds.get(i)).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot != null){
                    Book myBook = documentSnapshot.toObject(Book.class);
                    myBooks.add(myBook);
                    //Can not get out of this array from for loop
                }

            }
        });
    }

}


//I tried to make a nested query below but no result :(

  public void getBookListFromDb(){
    final ArrayList<String> myBookIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    CollectionReference bookIdRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.collection_users)).document(userId)
            .collection(getString(R.string.colleciton_books));

    bookIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            final ArrayList<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()){
                    myBookIds.add(ds.getString("book_id"));
                    myBookIds.size();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: myBookIds.size" + myBookIds.size());
                if (myBookIds.size()>0){
                    CollectionReference colRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.colleciton_books));
                    for (int i=0; i< myBookIds.size(); i++){

                        colRef.document(myBookIds.get(i)).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    DocumentSnapshot ds = task.getResult();
                                    Book myBook = ds.toObject(Book.class);
                                    myBooks.add(myBook);
                                }

                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: myBooks.size(i) "+ myBooks.size());
                            }
                        });
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: myBooks.size() in for "+ myBooks.size());
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: myBooks.size() "+ myBooks.size());

                }


            }
        }
    });
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want in this way because both methods, `onComplete()` and `onSuccess()` have an asynchronous behaviour. This means that by the time you are calling `getMyBooksFromDb()` method, you haven't finished getting the data from the database. So to solve this, you need to move all your logic from your `getMyBooksFromDb()` method inside `onComplete()` method. This is the flow:

- add a complete listener on your bookIdRef
- get all the `book_id` you have in your database by iteration using the foor loop
- inside `onComplete()` method use the `book_id` to create your `CollectionReference` for finding the books.
- Move the declaration of your `ArrayList<Book>` inside `onSuccess()` method.
- Do what you want to do with your list or with your `Book` objects.

So the solution is to use nested queries as explained above. So please use the following code:

```
CollectionReference bookIdRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.collection_users))
    .document(userId)
    .collection(getString(R.string.colleciton_books));

bookIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()) {
                String bookId = myBookIds.add(ds.getString("book_id"));

                dbRef.document(bookId).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (documentSnapshot != null){
                            Book myBook = documentSnapshot.toObject(Book.class);
                            Log.d("TAG", myBoog.getBookName());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I couldn't achive to get value with nested query, could you please write a code sample? Thanks.

Comment: Please add a detailed database structure so I can write you some code.

Comment: I have added some images that show my db's structure.

Comment: When you did you I recomended you, what was the problem? You has an error? Can you share the code you have used?

Comment: I dont get error, I tried to make a nested query but I couln't. My ArrayList always comes 0. I can not get the values out of "for loop".You can check "getBookListFromDb" method above.

Comment: One more question you are getting, are you getting the `myBookIds` correct?

Comment: Yes, I can get myBooksId as an ArrayList correctly.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I have added also a log statement to print the book names in the logcat. Does it work?

Comment: After I added two more methods, your perspective run, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Step -1:

Create a Model Class of `Userbook.java` and Book.java

```
Userbook.Java

String book_id;
Book book;

//create getter and setter for that.
```

As per you code set value:

```
UserBook userbook = new UserBook();

final ArrayList<UserBook> books = new ArrayList<String>();

public void getBookIdsFromDb(){


    CollectionReference bookIdRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.collection_users)).document(userId)
            .collection(getString(R.string.colleciton_books));

    bookIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()){
                   userbook.setBook_id(ds.getString("book_id"));

                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: myBookIds.size" + myBookIds.size());
                if (myBookIds.size()>0){
                    getMyBooksFromDb(myBookIds);
                    //this works
                }


            }
        }
    });
}
public void getMyBooksFromDb(ArrayList<String> bookIds){

    CollectionReference dbRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.colleciton_books));
    for (int i =0; i<myBooksIds.size();i++){
        Log.d(TAG, "getMyBooksFromDb: myBookIds in for " + myBooksIds.size());
        dbRef.document(myBooksIds.get(i)).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot != null){
                    Book myBook = documentSnapshot.toObject(Book.class);

                    userbook.setBook_id(myBook);
                    //Can not get out of this array from for loop
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
//after all this add obj to list
books.add(userbook);
```

I hope you will get the result. or else ping here.